# How To Find The Norm Of A Vector That Have Functions As Values?

Tags: vectors

So basically I have a 2 dimensional vector and the x and y coordinates are defined by functions.

$$X(x)  = (4x+2*2+cos(x))$$ 
$$Y(x) = (cos(x) + 5 * 2)$$

I was wondering how I can find the norm of this vector. Will appreciate any help. No idea how to use this MathJax thing though.

Comment: The Euclidean norm is $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$, if your two coordinates are $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Joe Alright thanks, just checking if it was different because they are functions.

Comment: Nope, still the same. You’re welcome.

Comment: Indeed, it's common to write a 2D unit vector as $x=\cos t,\,y=\sin t$.